# How do I automate killing a job in cron?

Tags: github, cron, raspberry-pi

I'm writing a program on a Raspberry Pi that needs to pull updates from GitHub every 24 hours. The program runs as a continuous loop, and doesn't end. The problem here is that the program, since it runs continuously, won't use the updated file. I need a way to automatically kill the job in cron, run the update code, then start the updated file again. Any ideas?